# Why there are no namespace routes generated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am stuck with the following code, trying to create a namespace route.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # skipping some lines for clarity
  devise_for :users
  authenticate :user do
    resources :approvals, only: [:update]
    namespace :approvals do
      resource :bulk, only: %i[approve reject], controller: :bulk
    end
  end
end
```

I am expecting to get an `approvals_bulk_approve_path` & `approvals_bulk_reject_path`, but no `bulk` controller routes are being generated. Result of `rails routes -c bulk` is empty.

Any idea what is the reason of this, anyone?

Comment: I have to say that the use of "bulk" as a singlular resource is pretty smelly. I would name it `bulk_imports` or something thats an actual resource (a noun).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`only:` only (ahem) works for standard actions (create, new, etc.).

Need to create custom actions...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  authenticate :user do
    resources :approvals, only: [:update]
    namespace :approvals do
      resource :bulk, controller: :bulk do
        collection do
          put :approve
          put :reject
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This assumes you want them generally available and not tied to a specific instance of `bulk`. If you want them tied to an instance of `bulk` change `collection` to `member`.

Comment: I was expecting to create only bulk#approve and bulk#reject with `only:` option - you are right, this will not work. Hovewer, with `resource :bulk` all CRUD actions are created, which might be not what you expect.

Comment: @adass `resource :bulk, only: [] do` or just `put "bulk/approve"` `put "bulk/reject"` or maybe `controller :bulk do`